# Connect between different row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

I have a table with 100 or more rows that are created at runtime in asp.net by `Table`.

This table shows projects of a user.

Different user have some different projects.

I want when admin clicks on row of name user show rows content list of user project (slideToggle).

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

```
 protected void btnShowProject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Project project = new Project();
        DataTable result = project.getAll( );

        Table table = new Table();            
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
        TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();
        
        tableCell.Text = "id";            
        tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

        tableCell = new TableCell();
        tableCell.Text = "name";
        tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

        table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
        tableRow = new TableRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < result.Columns.Count; j++)
            {

                tableCell = new TableCell();              
                tableCell.Text = result.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
            tableRow = new TableRow();
        }

        contentProject.Controls.Add( table);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take look to this: 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

I think this is what you want, try something from the examples. If you would have problems post back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain what you're asking, but if it's what I think you're asking, it's relatively simple.  Use the class attribute of the `<tr>`s that you want to show and hide.  Give each of them two classes - one should cover all of them (like, say, "userProjectTr" and one should be the name of the person who the project belongs to (which you also give to the name row).  Have the onclick function for the name row grab its class (ie, the user's name.  Call it "username" for the moment), then hide all tr.userProjectTr, then show all tr.username

All of this is pretty straightforward in jquery.  If you don't want to do it in jquery, for some reason, I'm less able to help you, and you should probably remove the jquery tag from your question.

Comment: jquery or java script or other way

Comment: So - is this what you need?  If not, why not?